# FindText: Giving window titles to Adobe After Effects panels that dont have window titles

Tags: autohotkey

## All child windows of Adobe After Effects and Premier Pro don't have any window titles

It seems the developers of Adobe After Effects and Premier Pro have seemingly gone out of their way to make both of these software's as AutoHotkey or automation unfriendly as possible.
All child windows of both programs don't have any window titles, neither do they have any unique and consistent class names or even window text. I am not exaggerating.
[image]

The Spy utility reports only the following for all child windows:

```
ahk_class DroverLord - Window Class
ahk_exe AfterFX.exe
ahk_pid 8860
```

Control names are unreliable, the program seems to apply a incrementing number to the end of the string `"DroverLord - Window Class"`  as windows are destroyed/created, the control text is the same across all panels but one:

```
ClassNN:    DroverLord - Window Class3
Text:   DroverLord - TabPanel Window
```

Descolada's UIAutomation is out of the question, [he himself has concluded as much](https://old.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/15s2twl/has_anyone_tried_using_descoladas_uiautomation/), at least for these two applications.

## What I am trying to do

Floating windows are important to how I work and also leveraging my AutoHotkey codebase, things are not any better with docked panels anyways. Same unreliable control names.
I have spent the day probing both of these applications trying to find a consistent entry point for AutoHotkey.

What I learnt is that if a window is given a title via AHK's `WinSetTitle`, that change is consistent, even if I change workspaces and reload a entirely different workspace, so long as that next workspace consists of floating windows, the title changes will remain.

I much proffer using window titles over Windows ID's, so process external to the running AHK script can also make use of this data, of which there are a few, including other AHK scripts.

I am looking to create a function, for example `AE_SetTitles()`, that will take all the child windows of After effects that do not have `AE_Window` in their title and essentially name them.

To identify which window is which, I am using Feiyue's [FindText](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17834&hilit=findtext) to find the following graphic on top left corner of **AE** every window lacking a title

---

## Code

Because the windows could be behind other windows at any given time, I need to make use of the `FindText().BindWindow()` method. The only way forward I can think of, is with a loop:

```
#singleinstance, force
#Persistent
#NoEnv
SetTitleMatchMode 2 
#Include <FindText>

Panels :="|<Project>*122$54.3zyzzjzzzRzzzzjzw0RX6ss7zzzRimqrjzzz3iukrjzw0TiurrjzzzTimrrjzzzTj6ssbzw0zzyzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzxzzzzzzU|<Tools>*122$46.zzzjzzzw3zyzzzzyzzvzzw0vllgTzzzimmrzzzyvffTzw0viiiTzzzimmxzzzywQN7zw0U|<Browser>*122$60.3zzzzzzzzzRzzzzzzzw0RX4qllXzzz3imarhjzzzRiuerVjzw0RiuftjjzzzRinNxjjzzz3j7Nlljzw0U"
WinGet, AE_Win, List, ahk_class DroverLord - Window Class ahk_exe AfterFX.exe ,, AE_Window ahk_exe AfterFX.exe
Loop,% AE_Win
    {
        WinId := AE_Win%A_Index%
        WinGetPos, winX, winY,,,% "Ahk_Id " WinId 

        FindText().BindWindow(WinId) 
        ok:=FindText(X, Y, winX, winY, winX + 100, winY + 50, 0, 0, Panels) ; Use the smallest region per window for speed
        OutputDebug, % Ok[1].id
        If (Ok[1].Id)
            WinSetTitle,% "Ahk_Id " WinId,,% "AE_ Window" Ok[1].Id
    }
```

I am stuck on, iterating or "walking" (not sure if I am using right terminology) the `ok` object. The above loop only sets title for the first found window. Loops are really my weakest point, indexing inside them is a nightmare for me.

Is a loop a must in this case? I know FindText can find one or more graphics in one call, but does it update the `WinId` value for  `FindText().BindWindow()` as it looks for the graphics, so it does not miss obscured windows.

The `ok` object looks like this in VSCode:

[image]

---

## Expected outcome

The end result I am looking for is, for all windows to have the prefix `"AE_Window"` then the name of the panel, so for the Toolbar panel it should be:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am not experienced with AAE, but isn't it scriptable with a built in scripting interface? Could that be used? For AHK first thing I thought is that are the windows a specific same size every time by any chance?

Comment: @0x464e, I looked into AAE scripting, it is unlike scripting in PS and AI. There is allot of first time set up and command ports that need to be established (not even for Ahk). Besides, this comapny is truelly incompetent, I doubt they will let you name their windows through their APIs.